# How to set up .NET reference source in Rider?

Tags: .net, jetbrains-ide, rider

I downloaded the [4.7.2 .NET Framework reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download_472.html) (the 'downlevel' variety) because I wanted to do some spelunking with my favourite Swiss Army knife in hand. Rider loaded the solution file alright but I'm having a hard time making the errors go away.

Most errors seem to be caused by Rider treating internal identifiers within a project like `mscorlib` as inaccessible, as though they were coming from outside the project (which may well be the case, as all of them are *also* defined in the framework assemblies). It is as though Rider gives precedence to symbols in (system) assemblies over symbols in the project source code.

Has anyone managed to make the .NET Framework reference source work with Rider? What's the trick?

NB: I'm using Rider 2023.1.2 under Windows 11; the source tar ball is `DotNet472Downlevel.zip` (*not* the `DotNet472RS4.zip` that is for Win10+) because the whole point of using 4.7.2 instead of 4.8+ is compatibility with older platforms.

Comment: The reference code is meant to be broken and only useful when the debugger steps into the source files from Microsoft symbols. So if you want to use the downloaded files in any other way, I don’t think Rider or even Visual Studio can help you out.